# How to prevent UIWebView from jumping to iTunes store?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

```
https://itunes.apple.com/album/colors-ep/id980949462?v0=9988&ign-mpt=uo%3D1
```

I wanna to display iTunes pages within the app through UIWebView, however when I try to do this, UIWebView will just jump to iTunes store, and nothing will be displayed in the UIWebView?

Comment: Does it happen on simulator as well?

Comment: I used this link https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/a-class/id450789230 and it opened up fine at my end.

Comment: It happens to me the same @iosDev82